# How to load Java Swing MainJFrame with classes instance and data from ANOTHER Java Class?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Hello Guys I have my swing application running but I need to create an "initialization class" where I create instances with data to populate the program when I run it 
If I create an instance with data in the MainJFrame constructor it's working perfectly but I need to populate the MainJFrame that will send it through all the panels from ANOTHER CLASS 
Here is my MainJFrame Code:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package UserInterface;


import Business.Initialization;
import Business.Inventory;
import Business.InventoryList;
import Business.Product;
import Business.ProductCatalog;
import Business.Store;
import Business.StoreDirectory;
import UserInterface.StarMarketAdmin.MarketAdminWorkArea;
import UserInterface.StoreAdmin.LoginStoreAdmin;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.util.Collections;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MainJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form MainJFrame
     */
    private StoreDirectory storeDirectory;
    private InventoryList inventoryList;
    private ProductCatalog productCatalog;
    private Store store;

    public MainJFrame() {
        initComponents();
        this.storeDirectory = new StoreDirectory();
        this.inventoryList = new InventoryList();
        this.productCatalog = new ProductCatalog();
        this.store = new Store();


    }


    private void btnMarketAdminActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        MarketAdminWorkArea panel = new MarketAdminWorkArea(userProcessContainer,storeDirectory,inventoryList,productCatalog,store);
        userProcessContainer.add("MarketAdminWorkArea", panel);
        CardLayout layout = (CardLayout) userProcessContainer.getLayout();
        layout.next(userProcessContainer);

    }                                              

    private void btnStoreAdminActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        LoginStoreAdmin panel = new LoginStoreAdmin(userProcessContainer,storeDirectory,inventoryList,productCatalog);
        userProcessContainer.add("LoginStoreAdmin", panel);
        CardLayout layout = (CardLayout) userProcessContainer.getLayout();
        layout.next(userProcessContainer);
    }                                             

}
```

Now if I create an instance like:

```
Store s = storeDirectory.addStore();
       s.setStoreName("Eddie's Market");
       s.setStreet("Plainfield Pike");
       s.setCity("Johnston");
       s.setState("RI");
       s.setCountry("USA");
```

in the MainJFrame it's working 100% but I need to create it in another class and call it in the MainJFrame to send it from there to all the other pannels.
How can I do this ?

Comment: see my last edit, by making  a public function to put it in the mainframe, you can create it somewhere else. and get it from other classes.

Comment: You will likely want to have a look at [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), it's an important concept, one which Swing does ues, but just like much of Swing, requires the developer to actually make an effort to utilise themselves

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create public functions to acces the private class from outside

not sure what you want exactly, but the options are endless

like

```
public void initStore(){ 
}
```

or just get it

```
public Store getStore(){ 
    retturn store;
}
```

or even create and return it from there:

```
public Store storeFactory(){
    // code here
    return store;
}
```

or if you want another store and return it

```
public Store storeFactory(){
    // code here to create a new store

    return store2;
}
```

*** NOT ADVISED but also an option: static  ***

you can also create a static one, even make it public, however public access is not the nicest way. Better keep it private and work with function as above to get it. In normally would not advice static usage like this... but assuming the MainFrame is the main program... in this case there might be an exception on the not to use static ....

```
private static Store store;
```

or

```
public static Store store;
```

than you can access it from everywhere by:

```
MainJFrame.store
```

*** end static remark ***

but maybe you just meant this:

```
public putStore(Store store){
    this.store=store;
}
```

so you can create it in other class, and get it from other classes

in the other class to create it you migth even first get it (init it in the mainFrame with null:

```
private Store store=null;
```

in the other class:

```
Store store = mainframe.getStore();
// code to create it
```

or only create it if not yet created:

```
if (store==null){
    // Only create if still null
    // code to create it here
}
// and here use it, just created or not
```

Migth be a weird and 'know it all' like advice, but:

all of the above is basic java knowledge about public, private, static and so on.... might look in to some tutorials, to understand the basic things.
Java can be a pain in the... in case you do not understand it (memory leaks and so on...) so please be sure you know what you do.... (in case you want to use it professionaly)

In java there is a big difference in declaring it, and initialising it:

this is a declaration:

```
private Store store:
```

this is the init:

```
store  = // something, even putting it to null is an init
```

and the combination of declare and init:

```
private Store store=null;
```

the last one you need before you can call it from other classes, because you actually will not get the object, but a pointer tot the object.
To have a pointer, you need tot init it, than init to null is enough.... so there is at least a pointer.
Understanding the way of pointers and how things are passed in java, will save some memory issues in bigger programs.

Comment: All I want is instead of writing:Store s = storeDirectory.addStore();
       s.setStoreName("Eddie's Market");
       s.setStreet("Plainfield Pike");
       s.setCity("Johnston");
       s.setState("RI");
       s.setCountry("USA"); In the MainJFrame Constructor I need to write it in another class and call it there I tried putting it in a public function in another class and call it in the mainjframe constructor but it didn't work I think because it's using another instance of storeDirectory for example that I have created in that particular class

Comment: you might make a static one, and use that one

Comment: you're welcome... by the way: I Am in favorite of learn by practice as well... :-)

Comment: `static` == `bad` (you can't control some one from changing the reference and basically destroying the application for example) and as a general should be avoided.  I might suggest a singleton, but that might be overkill for the problem (and it has it's own issues).  I think you're first suggestion is by far the more appropriate, passing a reference of `Store` through out the program, to the classes which need it

Comment: I agree, I just wanted him to know all the options. But having the class named MainFrame..... I assumed, this is the main program class... and all other classes will be terminated on terminating the mainframe.... like i said a lot of options, depending on the program what and hbow to use it.

Comment: I like options to, just not ones which can potentially have your or someone elses foot shot off :P

Comment: :-) I totally agree. So I added an extra warning in my summation of the options....

Answer (score 0):

Inject this Store instance into the MainJFrame constructor.
The Store class will hold the data and you can access it through get methods.

Have you thought about that?

Comment: Can you give me an example how ?

Comment: Of course. 
Make Store class member of MainJFrame. Instantiate it wherever you are already instantiating. Pass it as argument to MainJFrame.

MainJFrame(Store store) {
this.store = store;
}

If store is just a "data holder", you will need another class, another process to keep the information inside the store object up to date allowing MainJFrame to work with the latest you have.